# Windows C++ Redirect Libraries

Tags: c++, winapi, poco

I have a Microsoft VSTO project that I integrated some C++ libraries with (specifically POCO C++). I have been trying to put together an installer (64 bit version) and when I install I am seeing that some libraries are not being located. Explicitly using depends (dependency walker) is showing libraries like

```
--> api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll -> kernelbase.dll 
--> api-ms-win-core-xstate-l2-1-0.dll -> kernelbase.dll
--> api-ms-win-core-xstate-l2-1-1.dll -> kernelbase.dll 
--> api-ms-win-core-psapi-l1-1-0.dll -> kernelbase.dll 
--> api-ms-win-core-psapi-ansi-l1-1-0.dll -> kernelbase.dll
```

are showing as missing. Now these are defined as windows redirect libraries. But on a system they are showing as missing. Now I can install the application on development systems and these libraries show up ok. I thought it was possibly an incorrect VC++ target chain so I lowered to target CVS 2015. But same libraries show up as missing.

Can someone help describe how to identify and determine what deployment should be used (VS C++ wise).

Peter

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to undertstand that many old libraries have been *replaced* by **"umbrella"** libraries as explained here:

> An umbrella library is a single static-link library that exports a subset of Win32 APIs. For example, an umbrella library named OneCore.lib provides the exports for the subset of Win32 APIs that are common to all Windows 10 devices.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-umbrella-libraries
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis

---

For **W10**:

- [api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis#apis-from-api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0dll) Introduced in 10.0.14393
- [api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis#apis-from-api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1dll) Introduced in 10.0.10586. Moved into `api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll` in 10.0.14393.
- [api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis#apis-from-api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1dll) Introduced in 10.0.17134
- api-ms-win-ntuser-sysparams-l1-1-0.dll Not present on W10. Is a W7?